# A basic probability doubt on independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two i.i.d continuous random variable. I need to find the probability that $P(X_1 < X_2)$. I know how to formally find the probability by integrating over appropriate region and how we use the "identically distributed" and "independent" property here.

Now,consider the intuitive argument for this problem. $X_1$ and $X_2$ both have the same distribution. So, any one is equally likely to be the smallest. So, is n't identically distributed sufficient condition ? Where is "independence" needed here ?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose as an extreme example that $X_1=X_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X_1$ is a continuous uniform variable on the unit interval $[0,1]$, and let $X_2=X_1+0.01-\lfloor X_1+0.01\rfloor$.